# Triangle inequality in norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $X=\Bbb R^3$. For $x=(x(1),(x(2),x(3))\in X$, let
$$||x||=[(|x(1)|^2+|x(2)|^2)^{3/2}+|x(3)|^3]^{1/3}$$.
Then $||~||$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^3$.

\begin{align*}||x+y||&=[(|x(1)+y(1)|^2+|x(2)+y(2)|^2)^{3/2}+|x(3)+y(3)|^3]^{1/3}\\
&\leq [(|(x(1)|^2+|x(2)|^2)^{3/2}+(|y(1)|^2+|y(2)|^2)^{3/2}+|x(3)+y(3)|^3]^{1/3}~~~(\text{By Minkowaski's inequality})
\end{align*}
How to proceed next?
I am having difficulty while proving triangle inequality.

Comment: What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: @abiessu please have a look.

Comment: Downvoter please comment reason.

Comment: Looks like you have a good answer below.  I didn't downvote, but your initial post was very short and lacked demonstration of work that you might have done on the problem; this is often frowned upon in this community (as you may be aware).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can piggyback off of the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) for the $\ell^2$ and $\ell^3$ norms.

---

First,
$$(|x_1+y_1|^2 + |x_2+y_2|^2)^{1/2} \le (|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2)^{1/2} + (|y_1|^2+|y_2|^2)^{1/2}$$

Apply this inequality to the expression for $\|x+y\|$ at the end of your post to get
$$((|x_1+y_1|^2 + |x_2+y_2|^2)^{3/2} + |x_3+y_3|^3)^{1/3}
\le 
(((|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2)^{1/2} + (|y_1|^2+|y_2|^2)^{1/2})^{3} + |x_3+y_3|^3)^{1/3}
$$
Note that you made a small mistake here; you cannot replace the two powers of $1/2$ by a $3/2$.

---

Then carefully apply the Minkowski inequality for $\ell^3$ to bound the right-hand side by $\|x\|+\|y\|$ as desired. It may help to define $u_1 := (|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2)^{1/2}$, $v_1 := (|y_1|^2+|y_2|^2)^{1/2})^{3}$, $u_2:= x_3$, and $v_2:= y_3$ and to apply the $\ell^3$ inequality on $\|u+v\|_3 \le \|u\|_3 + \|v\|_3$.